# Icon Path which is in the .jar file

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, embedded-resource

my problem is, that the icon of my JFrame works in Eclipse but it dont work without.

I dont know what icon path i have to use if the txtIcon.png is in the .jar File.

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("txtIcon.png").getImage());
```

Please help me.

kind regards

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Answer (score 5):

This is VERY common problem

`ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the `String` value represents a file on the file system.  A resource is a `Jar` is NOT a file.

In order to load a resource that resides within the Jar file, you need to use `getClass().getResource(String)`.

Try changing it to `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/txtIcon.png"))`, assuming the `txtIcon.png` resides in the top level/default folder of the Jar

Comment: Oh nice thank you! ... its nice to know that i have to use getClass().getResource(String) if i try to load something out of the jar file... thank you! but... how can i fix the problem that i get a exception now if i run it in eclipse? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at main_tut3.Notepad.<init>(Notepad.java:52)
 at main_tut3.Notepad.main(Notepad.java:106)

Comment: Ah, I'm, unfortunately, not familiar with Eclipse...You should try searching SO, as this type of question comes up a LOT

Comment: I did it with try catch.... try {
   this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
     "/txtIcon.png")).getImage());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   
  }

Comment: From what I can summise, these resources need to be added to the `resource` folder in Eclipse.  There will automatically be included in the Jar and (as I read it), you can use `getClass().getResource("/resources/...")` to load them from within Eclipse and as a stand along Jar

Comment: Ahw damn dude ur a god.... it works now also without the try catch... i added a resource package to the src folder and copied the txtIcon.png in that package... then i used ur code 'getClass().getResource("/resources/txtIcon.png")' and now it works brilliant... Thank you very much!! i was trying it since 2 hours :D

Comment: @XenonUnlimited: wtf -- your catch block is empty. Why on earth?